# length of captured packets more than MTU

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, network-protocols

I m running iperf between two machines (linux) and I can observe the mtu of both the interfaces connected is 1500.

I ran tcpdump to capture packets and I  observed some packets have 
"length as 2962"....how come this is possible with mtu as only 1500?

Please clarify.
Thanks!

Note: flags field is set as DF. and proto is TCP

Comment: Turn off "Dont Fragment" flag????

Comment: Yes, and I asked what would happen if that was NOT SET.

Comment: I think i cannot..as it is iperf application which creates those packets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning off gso (in linux) did the trick

Referred:
http://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2008/11/14/20

Comment: you can do it using ethtool - like:  ethtool --offload <eth0> gso off